# "Expected expression in Swift key path" Error while Refactoring code with Extensions

Tags: ios, swift, refactoring, class-extensions

I have been trying refactor code by thanking functions and adding them in a separate file `extension` of a `ViewController`

What I have in this extension is a function that adds `gesture recognizers` to some views that have references to functions that I have placed in other file extension of the same `ViewController`. On build I am getting this error ***"Expected expression in Swift key path"***

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I got this error when I accidentally left a backslash after a bracket in my object init:

```
init(for note: Note, atAnchor anchor: ARAnchor) {\

    let billboardNode = note.type.basicNode

    self.node = billboardNode
    self.text = note.description ?? "[No Text]"
    self.type = note.type
    addText()
}
```

Removing the backslash fixed the error. Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55813790/8566348) by user eharo2 for details about why!

Comment: I am glad I am not the only one to have Googled this.

Comment: Weird, same. thx

Answer (score 9):

Maybe you have typo, for example:

```
\//
//  MyClass.swift
//  yyy
//
//  Created by xxx on 4/25/19.
//  Copyright © 2019 xxx. All rights reserved.
//

import Foundation

class MyClass {

}
```

In this Case I accidentally wrote '\' at start.

Comment: I actually did this same thing by accident. What are the chances that your exact answer fixed my problem lol

Comment: I did the same thing you mentioned here. thanks

Answer (score 3):

This error message is a straight forward error, where the parser is expecting a `keyPath`, given the usage of the backslash (assuming that this is the issue causing the problem, considering that the previous answer from @Edmund Holderbaum was accepted).

**Excerpt From: Apple Inc. “The Swift Programming Language (Swift 5.0).”**

> *Key-Path Expression.* A key-path expression refers to a property or
>   subscript of a type. You use key-path expressions in dynamic
>   programming tasks, such as key-value observing. They have the
>   following form:
>
> \type name.path

There seems to be few places in the Swift grammar where a backslash is used, other than in string interpolation (interpolated-text-item) or in a escaping sequence (escape-sequence).

from **Summary of the Grammar - Lexical Structure**

> “key-path-expression → \ type opt . key-path-components”

Take a look at this excellent post to learn more about `keyPaths` in Swift:  https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/the-power-of-key-paths-in-swift